# Full Product Catalog Import Possible?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, configurable-product, import

Is there any possible way to make one spread sheet that generates configurable products as well as all the simple products, link them and also contain image data? I have found "MAGMI" but it says I should do them in pieces of simple products then configurable products. I am trying to import a configurable tshirt product with simple sizes and colors.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Did you read? http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles

Comment: With magmi you can do it in a single file.you just need to put simple items before configurable ones. no need to split in two files.Read carefully magmi wiki about configurable & needed columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another answer with some information how to import simple/configurable keeping the associations using Magmi.  Looks like it should be possible:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16766075/1117286

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion and as far as I've used both Magmi and the native Magento Import/Export tool (introduced since v 1.5.x), the latter can represent an effective replacement to Magmi.

I suggest you to start from the following resource by Vinai Kopp

http://netzarbeiter.com/media/MagentoImagine/ImportExport.pdf

Regards,
Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but not out of box in Magento. If you consider paid extensions in order to accomplish this task check out  [this](http://productuploader.magelynx.com) one.

[Here is](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgOC3MxA5YaLdFFwTk9uY2RQbmthQmZZdmVYZ3FUOEE#gid=0) a sample format, check out tab "Configurable".

With this extension, you can import only configurable products, and it will automatically generate and auto-link needed associated simple products variants.

I think this might be a good alternative to the enterprise solution mentioned by Serpyre.